# Running executable application on Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, activexobject, wsh

Is it possible to run executable .exe application on Chrome browser or what option do I have?

I have seen example of JavaScript and it is desgined to work on IE because it use `WScript.Shell` (Not tested)

```
var ws = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
ws.run("C:\\System\\Display\\Display.exe \"" + message1 + "\" \"" + message2 + "\"");
```

So basically javascript it will execute `Display.exe <Message>`

Display.exe connect to COM3 (serial port) to display price on the Customer Display Pole (Till system)

Comment: No it only works because it uses ActiveX which IE supports and that has been locked down over the years to support less and less. How it should be done is the app registers a native protocol and then the script calls that protocol.

Comment: In a word, no. It used to be possible with Firefox, however that functionality was removed years ago. If you need an ActiveX, you need internet exploder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short: No it's not possible.

It's not even possible to call local files directly from chrome. It's really locked down in google chrome. If you manage to [crack it you could strike it rich](http://www.forbes.com/sites/andygreenberg/2012/02/28/google-will-offer-1-million-in-rewards-for-hacking-chrome-in-contest/#7ec11930ff99)

- In short, the best way to access local stuff is to set up a local webserver, call it, let the webserver execute a local file/protocol and then return the output to you via xhr or websockets.

  - Another option might be Java signed with secure certificates to allow some leeway, but even there the security measures are really tight.
  - Or you could make a chrome plugin and try [Native Message Passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#native-messaging)
  - Or, another option is that you fork chromium and build in your own activeX support into it. ChromiumX has a nice ring to it heh.

But all in all, it's really hard to get stuff done via chrome in what you want.

personally I resolved it by using PHP COM on a windows server to which I communicated via ajax requests to do the stuff I needed done, but it's less than ideal.

Comment: Instead of using Chrome browser directly, I am thinking using electron (http://electron.atom.io/) to create Desktop App (HTML, CSS, and JavaScript with Chromium and Node.js to build app) and let node.js can communicate with Serial Port, maybe using this one https://www.npmjs.com/package/serialport2 ... What do you think?

Comment: why, eh, not just make a executable and offer it for download... might save you more hassle, plus it allows better communication with hardware layer.
`"You are using chrome: please use internet explorer or use our trusted application(download here) to interface with your serial port"`